# Reverse for ''contact'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django, django-1.5

Not sure why i'm getting this error when the site has been working fine on runserver. Anyway, i'm getting the above error and i'm not sure why.

Here is my code and hopefully you can shed some light:

views.py

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.ContactUsForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    else:
        form = forms.ContactUsForm()

        return render(request, 'contact.html', {
                  'contact_form' : form,
        })
```

urls.py

```
 url('^thanks/$', 'contact_enquiries.views.contact', name="contact"),
```

Context processor as the form is included on everypage:

```
def contact(request):
        form = forms.ContactUsForm()

        return {
                  'contact_form' : form,
        }
```

HTML:

```
 <form action="{% url 'contact' %}" method="post">
```

Any help would be much appreciated. The idea is the form will redirect to the contact view. As the context processor can't render the form on every page.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are your `urlpatterns` namespaced?

Comment: If your app urls are namespaced, you should use {% url 'myapp:contact' %}.

Comment: What do you mean namescaped? I've tried this as above and got this: "'contact_enquiries" is not a registered namespace